# How can we launch multiple instances of an swt e4 rcp application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

How can we create a multiple instance of rcp e4 swt application even when one of the instance of application is launched .for ex like eclipseapplication .So how can this be done.

Comment: What platform (Mac, Linux, Unix, Windows)?

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous question?

Comment: i need to craete a workspace like as in eclipse such that when we close the application and re open the application the state has to be maintained .  @ Baz

Comment: It is for windows and linux @greg-449

Comment: So do you mean you want to know how to prompt for a workspace location during the startup or are you having problems getting multiple instances to run at all?

Comment: Ya now i need to know how to prompt for a workspace location during start up and create a instance of the application @greg-449

Comment: The prompt comes after a separate instance is started. There is no code in standard Eclipse to 'create an instance'

Comment: Ok Can you explain how the prompt can be displayed for a swt application.

Comment: Ok Can you explain how the prompt can be displayed for a swt application.as i am able to create instance but not able to maintain the state like displaying the same UI when restarted.so how the prompt can be made for swt application so that it creates a new instance in the workspace